# Add a method to an existing element

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

Trying to get my head around plugin development. Sorry if this is a super basic question. How do you add a method to an existing element? I’m trying to get any active Commerce 2 subscriptions for a user. I figured out how to add it as a variable to my plugin.

```
public function getActiveSubscriptions(int $userId): array
{
    return Subscription::find()
        ->userId($userId)
        ->status(Subscription::STATUS_ACTIVE)
        ->all();
}
```

It’s called by `{% set subscriptions = craft.myPlugin.getActiveSubscriptions(currentUser.id) %}`

That works, but I feel like the “right” way is to be able to do this `{% set subscriptions = currentUser.getActiveSubscriptions() %}` How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [Behaviors](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-behaviors). There is a good Working example made by Pixel and Tonic team within their Git for the [DotAll workshop](https://github.com/craftcms/ontherocks/blob/step-12/src/behaviors/UserBehavior.php)

```php
namespace ontherocks\behaviors;

use craft\elements\db\EntryQuery;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\elements\User;
use yii\base\Behavior;

/**
 * Class UserBehavior
 *
 * @property User $owner
 * @property EntryQuery $recipes
 */
class UserBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function getRecipes(): EntryQuery
    {
        if (!$this->owner->id) {
            // just return a query that is doomed to fail
            return Entry::find()
                ->id(false);
        }
        return Entry::find()
            ->section('recipes')
            ->authorId($this->owner->id);
    }
}
```

See how to attach behaviors

```php
// define user behavior
Event::on(User::class, Element::EVENT_DEFINE_BEHAVIORS, function(DefineBehaviorsEvent $event) {
    $event->behaviors[$this->id] = UserBehavior::class;
});
```

You can attach your custom behavior to the user class as well exactly like the code above and do

```twig
{% set user = currentUser %}
{% set subscriptions = user.getActiveSubscriptions() %}
```

Or you attach the behavior to the `SubscriptionQuery` and do

```twig
{% set subscriptions = craft.subcriptions.activeSubscriptions(currentUser).all() %}
```